# Error Promise is rejected: when running balance-transfer (hyperledger) with nodejs

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the steps to run the blockchain code from balance-transfer in the sample codes provided by hyperledger.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer.

Things work smoothly when I run it with golang but I get the following error when I run it with node.js.

```
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 254 "npm WARN example_cc@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

The error occurs when the chaincode is instantiated on the channel.

I am using node v8.6.0 and npm v5.3.0.

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code written in node.js has been removed in their latest release. I guess there was a problem with it.